# Unity [SerializeField] и инкапсуляция

Tags: unity3d, наследование

Когда в конце работы над проектом я хочу инкапсулировать код в своем проекте и убрать ненужные сериализуемые объекты т.е.

```
из [SerializeField] protected string name;  в  protected string name;
```

То все данные из этой переменной пропадают, (т.е. возвращает null).
Ключевое слово "protected" из-за того что данный код в "главном классе" или "классе-родитель" от которого наследуются другие классы.

Мой вопрос больше касается того, как делают при разработке игр разработчики, может эту переменную не нужно инкапсулировать а так и оставить?

Comment: SerializeField нужен, чтобы в поле, помеченным этим аттрибутом, находилась ссылка на объект со сцены/префаб/so и т.д. Естественно, когда ты убираешь этот аттрибут, то значение по умолчанию будет null. Как-то по-другому ты в монобех не пропихнешь компоненты со сцены.

Comment: @KOTlK не совсем верно. Програмно впихнуть можно запросто

Comment: "может эту переменную не нужно инкапсулировать а так и оставить?" , " как делают при разработке игр разработчики," --- всё **всегда** зависит от целей и задач. В данном случае неизвестно зачем делалось наследование и почему бы его не использовать. Также есть scriptableObject, который, как раз, возможно, нужно тут применить

Comment: Инкапсуляция это про типы и методы доступа, а не про атрибуты. Если ты не сериализуешь данные то их и не будет, в этом собственно и есть суть этого процесса... чему тут удивляться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я так понял что наследование нужно если "объекты" схожи друг с другом и имеют одинаковую функциональность или хотя бы схожую которую можно переопределить. К примеру класс "Animal" и наследуемые классы "Dog" "cat" и.т.д. + общие параметры. А scriptableObject это "шаблон" ячеек под разные объекты с одинаковыми типами данных. В голове не укладывается в чем особая разница между ними, Что наследование, что scriptiableObject подходят под  разные задачи. Дело наверно в том что при наследовании работают методы, а scriptable objects просто хранилище, хотя там тоже можно метод засунуть

Comment: Про scriptiableObject  я имел в виду, что для каждого класса применить какой-то заранее смоделированный объект, сохранить его как XXX.asset  и работать со сконфигурированным объектом......" Я так понял что наследование нужно если "объекты" схожи друг с другом и имеют одинаковую функциональность или хотя бы схожую которую можно переопределить. "  ---- ну типа того.....только зачем в текущем случае нужно было выставлять напоказ поле? Если задавать его из вне - то тогда его можно сделать и публичным, а если нет, то можно и приватным сделать и задавать в коде......

Comment: но если нужна гибкость в конфигурировании объекта то это, как я написал - scriptiableObject  и сохранение его как asset ....но это скорее всего для вас слишком сложно сейчас будет